# Two columns with text vertically centered

Tags: html, css

I need two columns:

- a button on the left
- a list on the right

And they both need to be vertically centered in the middle of the wrapper div. So far I got this:
https://jsfiddle.net/s1ky1hqr/1/

I used this code to vertically center the inline-blocks inside the wrapper:

```css
.wrapper {
  /* let it fill the whole container */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
.wrapper:before {

  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;

}

.column {

  display: inline-block;
  width: 48%;

}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column">

      <a class="cta" href="#">
        <span class="text">
          Button
        </span>
        <span class="arrow">
          >
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li><li>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a></li><li>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</footer>
```

The only problem is the ul list is not absolutely on the right, because the column divs aren't both 50% wide.
If I give both column divs a width of 50% the two divs won't fit next to each other. And I cannot "float" the column divs, cause in that case the text isn't vertically centered anymore.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Try flexbox https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use columns of `50%` width if you set the font-size to 0 inside your wrapper and reset it for your columns, like this:

```css
html { font-size: 12px; }
.wrapper {
  /* let it fill the whole container */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 0;
}
.wrapper:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column">
      <a class="cta" href="#">
        <span class="text">
          Button
        </span>
        <span class="arrow">
          >
        </span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li><li>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a></li><li>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Just so you know, it would also work if you remove all the whitespace from your HTML. Any whitespace after an inline-blocked element will be treated as a space character, and collapsed into one singular space - this is what causes them to be pushed to a next line. Good luck!

Comment: Yes I removed the whitespaces already from the inline-blocks by adding a break after the opening <li> tag :) And keep the </li><li> on the same line without spaces between them.

Comment: That seems really cumbersome, to be honest. It makes modifying your code a pain. I'm pretty sure once your `ul` is an inline-block, you could easily float your `li` elements and then add something like this to your `ul` css: `ul:after{content:'';width:100%;clear:both;}`, that way your list will get the correct height and your code can be formatted nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try that!

Answer (score 0):

You should add vertical-align:middle to .column instead .wrapper:before

Comment: This answer is better of as a comment. And you are so close to commenting - only 4 reputation!

Comment: I know its better as comment, but its because of reputation as you said :-/

Comment: The only thing I would tell you is that it's risky posting a comment as answer as some could downvote you, which will lower your reputation and put those comments a little further out of reach. Sorry about this, but the site works like this to make sure you add something to conversation before you comment!

Comment: No problem, Im glad for your warning, I'll take it on my mind, thanks.. I'm quite new in this community, so excuse me please..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by changing the `li` style to `display: block;` instead of `display: inline-block`, and getting rid of `float: right;` on the `ul` element.

[Here's your example, updated.](https://jsfiddle.net/s1ky1hqr/5/)